# Why is the relative import not working in my project?

Tags: python, import

I am working on a python project which consist of several packages and modules. Hence I need to import modules from different packages. However, when importing these modules I am getting import errors. The folder structure is as follows:
[Image of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrK6m.png)

Within the module Stage0.py I use the relative import: "from ..data.Datapipe import DataFactory" to import the class DataFactory. However when I execute the script I get an error message: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MT'"

I would appreciate any feedback as I'm becoming desperate

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood this correctly, but by the looks of it when you run the Stage0.py it will set the root python path to the app directory, the problem is that python's use of relative imports only allows to find files within that root directory, this site explains it a bit better to be honest

[See here](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html)

> Note that for relative imports, the dots . can go up only up to (but not including) the directory containing the script run from the command line

Anyway, it to fix it you could create a `__main__.py` file within the mt folder which calls the Stage0.py script, this will set that mt folder as the root of the project giving access to the other directories.

Comment: Hey Ryan. 
Thanks for the input, it seams to work if I create a __main__.py module. However, do you have any suggestion what this module should include. Now I it only contains an if __name__ == "__main__" and import from the app package.

Comment: Without knowing a little bit more context about what the scripts are doing it is hard to say

Comment: But essentially all your `__main__.py` file is doing at the moment is acting as a proxy for the other script allowing it to have mt as the root, it might be nicer to wrap that stage0.py in a function then call it in the `if name == main` part, but its up to you

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, I recommend that you put Stage0.py in the same location as the requirements.txt and execute it from there

as follows:

```
-data/
    -__init__.py
    -Datapipe.py
-graph/
    -__init__.py
    -s0.py
-stage0.py
```

stage0.py

`from data.Datapipe import DataFactory`

Comment: Thanks for the answer that seams to work, however, I would like have the module within a package as I want it to be scalable and have the possibility to add more modules later on.